# hook_user op load does not fire?

Tags: drupal

I have the following code in a custom module to save a session_id for comparison after logging in. I want to add it to the user object, so I called hook_user like so:

```
function mymodule_init() {
    global $user;

    if ($user->uid == 0 && !isset($_SESSION['anonymous_session_id'])) {
        $_SESSION['anonymous_session_id'] = session_id();
    }
}

function mymodule_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
    switch ($op) {
        case 'load':
            $user->anonymous_session_id = $_SESSION['anonymous_session_id'];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

However, it is not in the user object. There is a 'session' field that has a serialized array of $_SESSION information, which would mean I probably don't need hook_user, but why isn't this code working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues you're running into:

1. The user object in `hook_user()` isn't in `$user` (it's not one of the parameters): it's actually in `$account`.
2. The global `$user` object isn't fully loaded even after modifying `$account` during `hook_user()` (See [related issue](http://drupal.org/node/361471)).

To get the fully loaded user object, do this:

```
global $user;
$account = user_load(array($user->uid));
```

One thing to keep in mind is that, unless you run `user_save()`, information added to the `$user` object during `hook_user($op = 'load')` does not transfer from page to page: `hook_user()` is called every time the user is loaded, which is at least once a page. If you want to maintain session information without using the database, use `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Doh, totally did not notice $account. Been working with $user for 3 hours. The problem I am running into is when they log out, SESSION is regenerated and my custom value is lost there as well. I am trying to track a users actions on the site, from anon to auth (if they log in) and make sure they don't see a custom message twice.

Comment: Essentially, I need to have Drupal know if a user has seen a message before. I don't want an anon user to close a message, then log in, and see the message again, vice versa.

Comment: You need to create a cookie. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317066/how-to-store-session-cookie-in-drupal-6-on-the-computer-of-the-visitor/1325651#1325651 You can't save anything in the user or session objects because both are destroyed upon logout.